# TPL DataFlow confusion around pipelines - should I create a new pipeline for each data call? How can I track data that's flowing through?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm struggling with how to apply TPL DataFlow to my application.

I've got a bunch of parallel data operations I want to track and manage, previously [I was just using Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889760/managing-async-await-in-tasks-on-a-custom-task-scheduler-or-any-better-approach), but I'm trying to implement DataFlow to give me more control.

I'm composing a pipeline of tasks to say get the data and process it, here's an example of a pipeline to `get` data, `process` data, and `log` it as complete:

```
TransformBlock<string, string> loadDataFromFile = new TransformBlock<string, string>(filename =>
{
    // read the data file (takes a long time!)
    Console.WriteLine("Loading from " + filename);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    // return our result, for now just use the filename
    return filename + "_data";
});

TransformBlock<string, string> prodcessData = new TransformBlock<string, string>(data =>
{
    // process the data
    Console.WriteLine("Processiong data " + data);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    // return our result, for now just use the data string
    return data + "_processed";
});

TransformBlock<string, string> logProcessComplete= new TransformBlock<string, string>(data =>
{
    // Doesn't do anything to the data, just performs an 'action' (but still passses the data long, unlike ActionBlock)
    Console.WriteLine("Result " + data + " complete");
    return data;
});
```

I'm linking them together like this:

```
// create a pipeline
loadDataFromFile.LinkTo(prodcessData);
prodcessData.LinkTo(logProcessComplete);
```

I've been trying to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline).

My confusion is that in the tutorial this pipeline seems to be a 'fire once' operation. It creates the pipeline and fires it off once, and it completes. This seems counter to how the Dataflow library seems designed, I've read:

> The usual way of using TPL Dataflow is to create all the blocks, link
>   them together, and then start putting data in one end.

From "Concurrency in C# Cookbook" by Stephen Cleary.

But I'm not sure how to `track` the data after I've put said data 'in one end'. I need to be able to get the `processed` data from multiple parts of the program, say the user presses two buttons, one to get the data from "File1" and do something with it, one to get the data from "File2", I'd need something like this I think:

```
public async Task loadFile1ButtonPress()
{
    loadDataFromFile.Post("File1");
    var data = await logProcessComplete.ReceiveAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"Got data1: {data}");
}

public async Task loadFile2ButtonPress()
{
    loadDataFromFile.Post("File2");
    var data = await logProcessComplete.ReceiveAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"Got data2: {data}");
}
```

If these are performed 'synchronously' it works just fine, as there's only one piece of information flowing through the pipeline:

```
Console.WriteLine("waiting for File 1");
await loadFile1ButtonPress();
Console.WriteLine("waiting for File 2");
await loadFile2ButtonPress();
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Produces the expected output:

```
waiting for File 1
Loading from File1
Processiong data File1_data
Result File1_data_processed complete
Got data1: File1_data_processed
waiting for File 2
Loading from File2
Processiong data File2_data
Result File2_data_processed complete
Got data2: File2_data_processed
Done
```

This makes sense to me, it's just doing them one at a time:

[image]

However, the point is I want to run these operations in parallel and asynchronously. If I simulate this (say, the user pressing both 'buttons' in quick succession) with:

```
Console.WriteLine("waiting");
await Task.WhenAll(loadFile1ButtonPress(), loadFile2ButtonPress());
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Does this work if the second operation takes longer than the first?

[image]

I was expecting both to return the first data however (Originally this didn't 
work but it was a bug I've fixed - it does return the correct items now).

I was thinking I could link an `ActionBlock<string>` to perform the action with the data, something like:

```
public async Task loadFile1ButtonPress()
{
    loadDataFromFile.Post("File1");
    // instead of var data = await logProcessComplete.ReceiveAsync();

    logProcessComplete.LinkTo(new ActionBlock<string>(data =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Got data1: {data}");
    }));
}
```

But this is changing the pipeline completely, now `loadFile2ButtonPress` won't work at all as it's using that pipeline.

Can I create multiple pipelines with the same Blocks? Or should I be creating a whole new pipeline (and new blocks) for each 'operation' (that seems to defeat the point of using the Dataflow library at all)

Not sure if this is best place for Stackoverflow or something like Codereview? Might be a bit subjective.

Comment: Pipelines are *not* fire-once. They only stop when an unhandled error is thrown or you call `Complete()` on the first block *and* propagate completion. You don't need to create a new pipeline each time. Create it once and post as many files as you want. Call `Complete()` when you want to terminate your application and process any remaining messages

Comment: That's what I thought - so then how do I actually retrieve the specific *output* for a particular input?

Comment: BTW you don't propagate completion which means that if you call `Complete()` on `loadDataFromFile` completion won't propagate to `logProcessComplete`. Pass  a `DataflowLinkOptions` object with `PropagateCompletion` set to true to each `LinkTo` call

Comment: What do you want to do with the final output? Why don't you process it in the last block?

Comment: It'll be different for each item. One part of the application might be calling this to draw the 'data' on a graph, the other to export it to file etc.

Comment: Use a TaskCompletionSource, let it flow with the data through the pipeline and set it to completed at the pipeline end

Comment: @SirRufo no need for this. You *can* forward different messages to different blocks

Comment: @Joe `LinkTo` also accepts a predicate. You can linke one source to multiple targets based on some criteria, like the document type. This way you can send some outputs to a charting block, some to a logging etc. Instead of passing a simple string, create a message class that contains at least a flag that you can use to route the message

Comment: I see, if I use a Message class I could direct it through a more complex pipeline (could also contain a callback that gets fired at the end to return the data?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need some events to happen after some data has been processed, you should make your last block [`AsObservable`](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2013/01/31/mixing-tpl-dataflow-with-reactive-extensions/), and add some small code with `Rx.Net`:

```
var subscription = logProcessComplete.AsObservable();
subscription.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

As been said in comments, you can [link your blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline#forming-the-pipeline) to more than one block, [with a predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462705.aspx). Note, that in that case, message will be delivered only to **first** matching block. You also may create a [`BroadcastBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160447.aspx), which delivers a **copy** of the message to each linked block.

Make sure that unwanted by every other block messages are linked to [`NullTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462765.aspx), as in other case they will stay in your pipeline forever, and will stop your completion.

Check that your pipeline correctly handles completion, as in case of multiple links the completion also being propagated only to the first linked block.

Comment: Thanks. This answers the question but I still get the feeling tyring to use DataFlow to manage tasks is fitting a square peg into a round hole. Interesting that you bring up Rx - I've used that and DataFlow reminds me of it - perfect for *stream* type data, or where you've got sources/publishers of data, and want to react to it. It doesn't feel like it's helping me solve the original problem (scheduling and monitoring *tasks* with data) as such.

Comment: `Rx.Net` can be easily used for notifying you about some data passed through the pipeline, it's like `fork` operation. The `TPL Dataflow` itself wasn't designed to provide status for particular message inside it.

Comment: "The TPL Dataflow itself wasn't designed to provide status for particular message inside it" - have you ever dumped Dataflow blocks in LINQPad?  They get visualized very nicely. But however it is done, it must be internal "magic" not available through public members.

Comment: LinqPad isn't the part of the TPL Dataflow. Moreover, I think it's just using the task analysis, as the TPLDataflow is built over the TPL.

Comment: @VMAtm, am I correct in my interpretation that a `BroadcastBlock` ***never*** needs a `NullTarget` if it is linked to another block with a predicate?

Comment: @MattDavis No, that's incorrect. I only suggested the `BroadcastBlock` if you need to deliver to all the targets, not only the first matching with predicate. If predicate doesn't match, the message will stay in output forever

Comment: @VMAtm, thanks for the quick response.  We use a `BroadcastBlock` to send messages to various parts of our system.  Those parts link to a single `BroadcastBlock`, and some use predicates to filter the messages ahead of time.  Just to be clear, are you saying that we should put a `NullTarget` on the `BroadcastBlock` in a case like this?

Comment: @MattDavis You said, that **some** of them are using predicates. In that case the `NullTarget` isn't necessary, as message will definitely be handled (but it's not guaranteed  that that message will be handled by blocks with predicates, which is excpeted)